For an array of size=n , a1,a2,a3,...,an . minimize max(a)-min(a) by this operation : choosing index i ,set a[i] = a[i]-1; and a[i+1] = a[i+1]+1;
Problem Statement :
You are given an array a of size n. array a = {a[1],a[2],....,a[n]}. You can do the following operation as many times as possible .

choose any index i
set a[i] = a[i] - 1  and a[i+1] = a[i+1]+1;
Now the task is to minimize max(a[1],a[2],....a[n]) - min(a[1],a[2],....a[n]) , that is minimize the difference of the maximum element of a and minimum element of a.


Sample Test Case :
n = 5;
a = {5 14 4 10 2}


My solution

I am able to observe that after applying operation sufficient number of times , the array a will be increasing , that is a[1] <= a[2] <= a[3] ,....<=a[n].
So my algorithm is as follows >>
Algorithm : while array is still decreasing , that is for some j , a[j] > a[j+1] in the array a we do the following :
let me show you by doing my algorithm on the given sample test case
a = [5,14,4,10,2] , array is decreasing , cause 14 > 4;
now


i = 1 , 5 < 14 , go ahead


i = 2 , 14 > 4 , so now changed array a = [5 , 9 , 9 , 10 , 2] by doing operation


i = 3, 9 < 10 , go ahead


i = 4 , 10 > 2 , so now changed array a = [5 , 9 , 9 , 6 , 6 ] by doing operation (we are basically equalizing them , that is if for some j, a[j] > a[j+1] make them equal by using the operations)


This cocludes our first iteration but still the array a is decreasing for i = 3 , 9 > 6
so we do the above same process for this newly formed array a = [5,9,9,6,6] and so on ,
I have calculated and found out that finally a becomes a = [5,7,7,8,8]
now the minmized answer = a[n] - a[1] , answer = 8-5 = 3; for above. so we have minimized the difference to 3 .
My Confusion :


Though this algorithm gives us the answer but it is too slow . is there any way to make this algorithm fast to maybe O(n) time complexity . There is also one solution which is >>


Another Algorithm
You try to find maximal minimum for all prefixes, and minimal maximum for all suffixes. The answer is their difference. To calculate minimums for prefixes, you can use sum of the elements, and "balance" all of them. For the sum S
of a prefix, and its length L
, the maximal minimum is ⌊S/L⌋
. Similar works for suffixes. I have copied this algorithm from someone else's solution and this is not mine , but I do not understand this at all ,
Main question : Can you please explain how this above algorithm of prefix and suffix works and help me with proving the algorithm , and is it possible to make my original algorithm to O(n) ? if so can you just give me an idea how this would work ?

